# Convert JSON date to date for storing in core data

Tags: ios, date, core-data

I receive a date from a web service in JSON.

I want to store it in core-data and after getting an error trying to do so, read that JSON comes across as plain text.

I therefore implemented some code to convert it to a date. However, the date is still not saving.  No errors are thrown but it does give a warning in yellow: `initializing NSString with an expression of type NSDate`.

Here is code:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
                [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];

    //Following line shows yellow warning:Incompatible pointer types initializing NSString with an expression of type NSDate.
                NSString *creationdatestr = importItem.creationDate;
 NSDate *creationdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:creationdatestr];
```

Of note, when I log both creationdate and creationdatestr to console they both look identical as below so it could be nothing is happening from dateFormatter.  In any case, neither version saves properly into a date field:

```
creation date:2015-10-16 11:05:57
creation date as date:2015-10-16 11:05:57
```

Would appreciate any suggestions.

**Edit:**

This is method that captures JSON feed and assigns it to object.  It seems to capture the JSON fine, however, I cannot tell what the data type of the incoming JSON is.  After all, it is just arriving in text and I don't know how IOS figures out what data type to make incoming text.

In the IDItemFromServer object, date is defined as a property of type NSDate.

```
- (NSArray *) convertFeedtoObject:(NSArray*)feed {
    // Create an array to store the locations
    NSMutableArray *_items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    for (int i = 0; i < feed.count; i++) {
        NSDictionary *feedElement = feed[i];
        IDItemFromServer *newItem = [[IDItemFromServer alloc] init];
        newItem.name = feedElement[@"name"];
        newItem.date = feedElement(@"date");
NSLog(@"newItem.date");//this logs what looks like a date.
```

Comment: I don't understand. NSLog (@"%@", object), will call `[object description]`. It's not because [object1 description] and [object2 description] show the same values that they are from the same class...

Comment: I took out the NSLogs

Comment: It would appear that `importItem.creationDate` is an `NSDate *`, correct?

Comment: I guess it is.  However, it does not save into a date field in core data for some reason.

Comment: error msg is:Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "creationdate"; desired type = NSDate; given type = __NSCFString; value = 2015-10-13 11:08:21

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *creationdatestr = importItem.creationDate;
```

From your warning/error is not a `NSString`, it is a `NSDate`.

```
NSDate *creationdate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:creationdatestr];
```

Therefore this line of code is wrong.

What is `importItem`?  Is it your `NSManagedObject` subclass?  If so, you are trying to convert an existing `NSDate` object into a `NSString` and that doesn't work as it is already a `NSDate`.

Comment: That makes sense and I just tried declaring it as an NSDate and saving but it seems to be a NSCF-String which I read is a flavor of NSString.  Saving returned this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unacceptable type of value for attribute: property = "creationdate"; desired type = NSDate; given type = __NSCFString; value = 2015-10-13 11:08:21.'

Comment: importItem is an NSManagedObject subclass for importing.  It has an NSDate *  creation date property so it wants an NSDate.

Comment: I tested if with isKindOfClass and, tested that way it is a string, contrary to the yellow warning message.

Comment: Then `importItem.creationDate` will always return either a `nil` or a `NSDate`.  It will **NEVER** return a `NSString`.  Further how are you using a data object like a `NSManagedObject` to import?  Where is the code that **SETS** the value of `creationDate` from the JSON?